# How to Filter an Unknown Number of Values of an Array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filter, filtering

I have a json list of languages in which I filter according to a database.

On my json list there are 20  names of languages (called 'langs'), and the database delivers me the languages of the user in a form of an array: ['english', 'german', 'spanish'], called 'sLangs'. In most cases, it gives 1 - 3 language names, but it could be more.

What I could not figure out is how to code the .filter() function correctly. Right now, I do this:

```
langs.filter(
        (langs) =>
        langs.name === sLangs[0] ||
        langs.name === sLangs[1] ||
        langs.name === sLangs[2] ||
        langs.name === sLangs[3] ||
        langs.name === sLangs[4]
)
```

Which does the job, but of course gives me undefineds.

Comment: I am not quite sure what the actual question is. What is the expected result?

Comment: [Array.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) will probably help. Like: `sLangs.includes(langs.name)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```js
const sLangs = ['english', 'german', 'spanish']

const langs = [{
    name: 'english',
  },
  {
    name: 'swedish',
  }
]


const res = langs.filter(lang => sLangs.includes(lang.name))

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this something you need?

```js
langs.filter(lang => sLangs.includes(lang.name))
```

Answer (score -1):

Make an array of excluded language. Then, use that array like this:

```
langArray = ["German", "Spanish", "Arabic", "Danish","Mandarin"];
excludedArray = ["German", "Spanish", "Arabic"];
filteredArray = langArray.filter(function(el) {
  return !excludedArray.includes(el);
});
```

`filteredArray` will be the array you wanted.